# Parameterized pandas data frame names

Tags: python, pandas

How do I create a data frame with a name that resolves from a variable? From the example below I would like to created dataframe pd0,pd2..pd10

```
for i in range(0,10):
    pd + "i" = pd.DataFrame()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
In my opinion, its better to track them in a dictionary.

```
dfs = {'pd{}'.format(i): pd.DataFrame() for i in range(10)}
```

Access them

```
dfs['pd0']
```

---

**Option 2**
But if you insist on placing the names into the namespace

```
for i in range(10):
    exec('pd{} = pd.DataFrame();'.format(i))
```

---

**Option 3**
Or without `exec`

```
for i in range(10):
    locals()['pd{}'.format(i)] = pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: thanks for the inputs @piRSquared. How about if I initially create 2 dataframes then add more, how will I be able to do that?

Comment: @user3694537 Is it not clear how to add as many as you'd like given the examples I've shown?  `pd1 = pd.DataFrame(); pd2 = pd.DataFrame(); for i in range(2, 10): exec('pd{} = pd.DataFrame();'.format(i))`

Comment: I use dfs.update to add items in the dictionary if my loop requires to create another dataframe